How to publish a survey with proper branding?
I am very very new to SharePoint, so I might mix up terminologies. Apologies.
We have an intranet portal which is a SharePoint 2019 on-premise instance. The main public site has a specific branding, look and feel, logos etc.
Now I want to create a new survey in this main user facing site and publish the survey link to our customers. Users would click on the link and contribute. So I created a survey, by adding "Survey" app to our root "Site Contents".
Problem:
But the final page has SharePoint branding, not our main website branding. What I mean by this is, the resulting page has SharePoint interface elements, like recent menus on the side, various sub sites on the top etc. For e.g. something like this:

I don't want this. I want the final page to look like any other page on our user facing site.
I know I am missing something silly. May be I created the survey in the wrong subsite?
What I tried:
So I created a new web page in our main site, so this page now has the proper branding. And into this page, I added the survey page as an iframe, via script editor web part.
This looks neat, except it has few problems:

when user clicks the "Finish" button there is no proper redirection or success message shown. Instead it shows an empty page.
The user can't see his response.
If the user is loading the page twice, he will see an exception message (because user has already attempted the survey).

I basically want the all the features of original survey page, except the look and feel should not be like a configuration page.
